# Data not loading after converting from single page to multi page app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I am new to frontend and web development and have run into a blocker.  I had originally developed my website to be a single page application, after some feedback I decided to convert it into a multi-page application.  Everything works fine as a single page, but when I load up the same HTML as another page, the data from my ajax calls and the HTML I am generating with javascript do not get displayed.

Relevant code (please let me know if I need to provide more).

upon clicking the `exp-button` generated from this method:

```
let generateCards = function (data) {
    experiments = data;
    data.forEach(element => {
        let end = new Date(element.endDate);
        daysLeft = dateDiffInDays(today(), end);


        if (daysLeft <= 0) {
            daysLeft = "Experiment Ended";
        }

        if (daysLeft === 1) {
            daysLeft = "Ends Today";
        }

        let cardHtml = '<div class="card-container .col-md-4 .offset-md-4">' +
            '<div class="cardImg">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="experiment">' +
            'EXPERIMENT' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="experiment-name">' +
            element.title +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="experiment-description">' +
            element.shortDescription +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="experiment-time-remaining">' +
            daysLeft + ' days left' +
            '</div>' +
            `<a class="exp-button"  data-experiment="${element.id}">` +
            '<div class="experiment-button">' +
            '<div class="button-text">' +
            'LEARN MORE' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</div>';
        $('#cards-container').append(cardHtml);
    });
};
```

note I have also tried this line of code instead of the method below:

```
`<a class="exp-button" href="experiment.html" onclick=loadLearnMore(${element.id}) data-experiment="${element.id}">`
```

click method (inside a `$(document).ready(function ()`):

```
$(document).on('click', '.exp-button', function (event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr("data-experiment");
    loadLearnMore(id);
    window.location.href= "/experiment.html";
});
```

This should fire off this method, I hit breakpoints in some of the configurations I tried, but never is the data displayed:

```
let loadLearnMore = function (id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:55345/api/ExperimentParticipant",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(id),
        success: function (res) {
        },
        error: function (data, err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }).done(function (result) {
        $("#participants").html('');
        $("#participants").append(result);
        experiment = experiments.filter(e => e.id == id);
        $("#days-remain").html('');
        $("#days-remain").append(dateDiffInDays(today(), new Date(experiment[0].endDate)));
        $(".experiment-text-learn").html('');
        $(".experiment-text-learn").append(experiment[0].title);
        $(".about-text").html('');
        $(".about-text").append(experiment[0].longDescription);
        $(".duration-text").html('');
        $(".duration-text").append(longDate(new Date(experiment[0].startDate)) + ' - ' + longDate(new Date(experiment[0].endDate)));
        $('#join-button').attr("data-experiment", id);
        loadRequirements(id);
        loadUpdates(id);
        loadNextStaps(id);

    });
};
```

Other methods used in the previous method:

```
let loadNextStaps = function (id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:55345/api/join/" + id,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (res) { },
        error: function (data, err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }).done(function (result) {
        let steps = (JSON.parse(result));
        let content = '';
        steps.forEach(element => {
            var media;
            content += `<div>${element.number}.&nbsp;&nbsp;${element.step}</div>`;
            if (element.isApp === true) {
                media = element.mediaUrl.split(' ');
                if(media[0] != 'null'){
                    content += `<a href='${element.appleUrl}' target='_blank'><img src='${media[0]}' alt='app store logo'></img></a>`;
                }
                if(media[1] != 'null'){
                    content += `<a href='${element.androidUrl}' target='_blank'><img src='${media[1]}' alt='google play logo'></img></a>`;
                }
            }
        });
        $("#next").html('');
        $("#next").append(content);
    });
};

let loadUpdates = function (id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:55345/api/updates/" + id,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (res) { },
        error: function (data, err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }).done(function (result) {
        let updates = (JSON.parse(result));
        let content = '';
        updates.forEach(element => {
            content += `<div class='update-time'>${timeSince(element.date)}</div>` + //time since
                `<div class='update-title'>${element.title}</div>` + //title
                "<div class='update-text-container col-md-8'>" +
                "<div class='update-text'>" +
                `${element.content}` + //update content
                "</div>" +
                "</div>";
        });
        $("#profile").html('');
        $("#profile").append(content);
    });
};

let loadRequirements = function (id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:55345/api/requirements/" + id,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (res) { },
        error: function (data, err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }).done(function (result) {
        let requirements = (JSON.parse(result));
        $('.requiirement-list').html('');
        requirements.forEach(element => {
            $('.requiirement-list').append(`<li class="requiirement-item">${element.content}</li>`);
        });

    });
};
```

Comment: Once you navigate to a new url or a page is reloaded (the way you have done with window.location.href = "/experiment.html";) , any javascript that is running will not be executed. I suggest that when the .exp-button is clicked you firstly navigate to the new page (e.g experiment.html and pass in the id as a parameter to the new page) and then on that page you execute the javascript/ajax request (you could do this in a document.ready function or window.onload function so that it would execute on page load)

Comment: As you are new to multipage websites I just wanted to add a bit of info to help: If you have a script that you want to use on all pages of your multipage website then you need to include it on ALL of the pages. Each page is a new "document" whereas with a single page app the whole thing is one "document".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see in your code is:

When `.exp-button` is clicked the `loadLearnMore` function will execute for the current page (say its `index.html`) and then immediately after this is executed you are navigating to a new page (experiment.html) so any changes that the javascript code just made to the page will not be visible as you are now on a new page.

I suggest that when the `.exp-button` is clicked you firstly navigate to the new page (e.g `experiment.html` and pass in the id as a parameter to the new page) and then on that page you execute the javascript/ajax request.

Here is some basic code to show how it could work (i know you're generating the html dynamically and that would work fine too but I have just hard-coded it to demonstrate):

## index.html (the current page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index page</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('click', '.exp-button', function (event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr("data-experiment");
    //navigate to experiment.html passing the id as a parameter.
    window.location.href= "experiment.html?id=" + id;
  });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="cards-container">
    <a class="exp-button" data-experiment="1">learn more</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## experiment.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Experiment page</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//get the url parameters sent
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
//get the id parameter and store it in a global variable
var id = urlParams.get('id');
console.log(id);

$(document).ready(function(){
  //do ajax request with the id parameter. This could also be in a loadLearnMore function but Im keeping it basic for demonstration purposes.
   $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:55345/api/ExperimentParticipant",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(id),
        success: function (res) {
        },
        error: function (data, err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }).done(function (result) {
      //now that we have the data/result we can insert it to the elements of the current page that we are on as follows.
      $("#participants").html('');
      $("#participants").append(result);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="participants"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So essentially I need to have multiple `$(document).ready(function(){` to solve my issue?

Comment: If I'm not missing something here and you're talking about making a website the old school way (e.g before the days of single page apps) with multiple pages then Yes, you would have a document.ready on each page. And every page should be a full HTML document with the <!DOCTYPE html> tag. Do you want to show me your full code somewhere, so i can see what way it is structured?

Comment: I think I understand now, When I load a new/different page I am loading a new document, so I need a document.ready function for that specific page to handle the logic for that page.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @JasonSowers Yes that's it. no probs :)

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.href= "/experiment.html";`

remove this line

youre navigating the browser away before the remaining script can execute.

Comment: how would you suggest navigating to the new page then?

Comment: If its a single page app all the application logic lives on one page (including subsequent pages). To update the view on click, your AJAX will replace the contents of the HTML elements not navigating away. That said, if you want to handle routes in a SPA youll need to write special server logic to account for that  and always redirect the browser to the index.html